# Composer list packages with installed version and latest version

Tags: composer-php

As in the title, is there any command that can list installed packages and the latest version of those packages together?

---

edit:

```
php composer.phar show
```

this show all available packages and also installed packages with installed version only

```
php composer.phar show [package]
```

this can get both installed version and latest version, but it is inconvenience if many packages are installed

Answer (score 62):

Since [Composer v1.1](https://github.com/composer/composer/releases/tag/1.1.0) (May 2016) you can run

`composer outdated`

Comment: or composer outdated -D (to show only the packages directly required by the root package)

Answer (score 59):

According to the docs https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#show

```
composer show -l
```

or

```
composer show --latest
```

will "List all installed packages including their latest version"

Here are a few lines of my output:

```
beberlei/assert              v2.5    v2.7.8  Thin assertion library for...
behat/transliterator         v1.1.0  v1.2.0  String transliterator
clue/stream-filter           v1.3.0  v1.4.0  A simple and modern approa...
fgrosse/phpasn1              1.3.2   1.3.2   A PHP Framework that allow...
```

This worked on composer 1.2 and 1.5.2

Answer (score 46):

As the current version of composer `-i` option which tells composer to show only the installed version is deprecated.

So if you want to show only the installed version of a package, the syntax is:

```
composer show "package-name"
```

If you need to pull all available versions of the package, use `--all` option like this:

```
composer show "phpunit/phpunit" --all
```

Comment: [composer show "phpunit/phpunit" --all] - do you know how to narrow down the output of this command to just the lists of versions? Because there is a bunch of useless information as well.

Comment: The OP asked for a solution that works for more than one package. Can you explain how your solutions solves this requirement?

Comment: To improve this answer, the first example should be `vendor-name/package-name`, just `package-name` by itself fails with "Package name <package-name> not found".

Answer (score 13):

I think

```
php composer show -i
```

is what you're looking for.

Comment: Worth noting: "You are using the deprecated option "installed". Only installed packages are shown by default now. The --all option can be used to show all packages." Got this with Composer 1.2.0.

Answer (score 9):

**`--outdated` option**

Perhaps, you are looking for `--outdated` option.
It will make output like this:

```
zendframework/zend-db  2.9.2  2.9.3  Database abstraction layer, SQL...
```

`2.9.2  2.9.3` - installed and new available version (according to instructions in composer files).

**`--all` option**

I guess it `--all` should work for you within one package.

It will show your current version with the asterisk. It will look like this:

```
dev-master, v0.1.2-alpha.0, * v0.1.1-alpha.0, v0.1.0-alpha.1, v0.1.0-alpha.0, dev-develop
```

So, I have installed `v0.1.1-alpha.0`.

**`--available` option**

Also, there is `--available` option to new version.

> --available (-a): List available packages only.

https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#show

Example:

```
composer show --available monolog/monolog 1.0.2
```

In this case it will make request to available composer repositories, packagist.org or your custom ones.

P.S. My GIT version: `2.14.1`

Answer (score 4):

use this:

```
composer update --dry-run
```

it gives both your current versions and the latest versions of your bundles

Comment: Not quite: it only shows which updates **meeting your version requirements** are available. For example if you require `2.*` but version `3.0.0` is available, `composer install --dry-run` won't tell you that, it'll only tell you if a greater `2.*` version is available. `composer outdated` will, thanks @daker.

Answer (score 1):

To just show top-level packages (listed in `composer.json`), I use:

```
composer show -t | grep -v "[|\`]--" | grep -v "[└├]"
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for! Worked for me