# Composer - can you find and install the "latest" version of a package?

Tags: php, composer-php

I feel like this should be a lot easier, but maybe it's not possible. I've read:

- [Composer list packages with installed version and latest version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32262970/composer-list-packages-with-installed-version-and-latest-version)
- https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md#exact-version-constraint

I have an application that's a few years old written in CakePHP 3. According to the [upgrade guide for CakePHP 4](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/appendices/4-0-upgrade-guide.html)

> First, check that your application is running on latest CakePHP 3.x version.

In my `composer.json` I have this:

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.6",
    "cakephp/cakephp": "3.8.*",
    // ...
},
```

I can see it's installed 3.8.12:

```
% cat vendor/cakephp/cakephp/VERSION.txt
3.8.12
```

How do I find out what the "latest version" of CakePHP 3.x is? Can Composer identify this and install it for me? Or do I need to manually find out and then update my `composer.json` to a **specific version** of CakePHP 3.x? I can see in the composer docs how to specific a specific version. But I can't see any information about how you find out what the latest version is?

If I run `composer show` it will output

> cakephp/cakephp                    3.8.12  The CakePHP framework

But this is misleading because there are, for example, versions such as CakePHP [3.9](https://bakery.cakephp.org/2020/06/20/cakephp_390_released.html) or [3.10](https://bakery.cakephp.org/2021/10/29/cakephp_3101_released.html), etc which are still in the 3.x range but "later" than 3.8.12

Comment: Upgrading automatically to a major version (e.g. from 3 to 4) would lead in most cases to unforeseen problems.  But you can change your composer.json to install any 3.* version by changing it to `"cakephp/cakephp": "3.*",`

Comment: You can use `composer outdated`, which shows all of the packages that are outdated. However, it doesn't always show the major version changes, so it may not show what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks Andrea. This was unclear in the docs but has worked. I now have 3.10.2 installed

Comment: @aynber if I run that it gives 4.3.7. Although that's the version I eventually want to upgrade to, the upgrade tool for CakePHP requires that you install the "latest" 3.x first. So the method Andrea gives in the comments, `"3.*",` in composer.json works.